# Most optimized strstr() like function for my code

Tags: c, parsing, search, optimization, strstr

Im writing http parser and have these functions

```
int parse_useragent(char* buf, int length){
    buf[length] = '\0';
    if(strstr(buf, "MSIE") != NULL){
        return 1;
    }else if(strstr(buf, "Firefox") != NULL){
        return 2;
    }
    return DEFAULT_USERAGENT;
}

void parse_headers(unsigned char* buf, http_record_t * http){
    char * position = (char*)buf;
    char referer[] = "Referer";
    char useragent[] = "User-Agent";
    ...
    int length = getlinelength(position); // returns length of line
    while(length != 1){ // position points to start of line every iteration of cycle
        if(strncmp(position, useragent, sizeof(useragent)-1) == 0){
            http->useragent = parse_useragent(position, length);
            fprintf(stderr,"parsing useragent \n");
        }else if(strncmp(position, referer, sizeof(referer)-1) == 0){
            fprintf(stderr,"parsing referer \n");
            char * tmp = malloc(REFERER_LENGHT * sizeof(char));
            parse_referer(tmp,position, length);
            strncpy(http->referer,tmp, REFERER_LENGHT * sizeof(char) - 1);
        }else if(...

        position += length + 1;
        length = getlinelength(position);
    }
    return;
}
```

`buf` points to start of http headers.

I have function like `parse_useragent` for each header and I really need to optimize them.
Length of packet is usually <1000 and length of line rarely exceeds 100 value. 
Will optimisation on such short strings have any noticable effect?

I know that some of these algorithms require different approach of parsing then line-by-line. Which way to choose under these specific conditions?

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/250566/Fastest-strstr-like-function-in-C
- http://www.sanmayce.com/Railgun/index.html

Thanks for help!

Comment: I see one problem in that you increase the buffer pointer `position` with `length + 1`, but remember that all lines in the HTTP header should be terminated with `\r\n` so you might have to increase the pointer with `length + 2`.

Comment: `getlinelength(position)` already returns length incremented by 1. This code works fine, I just need it to be faster. Thanks for notice though...

Comment: `parse_referer(http->referer,position, length);` ,and remove the tmp (which also is a memory leak) ; `parseparse_referer(http->referer,position+sizeof referer, length-sizeof referer);` is marginally faster. The strncpy() is wrong, as always.

Comment: BTW: do you need to recognise **only two** header lines, anchored at the begin of line?

Comment: No, I will parse around 10 header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind hard code the string into the code, I think lex would be the fastest tool to do this kind of task. Because it builds a finite state automaton explicitly in the source code.

Here's the sample lex code to do this task:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
enum Type{
    TFIREFOX = 0, TMSIE = 1
};
enum Type global_variable; /* the variable to store the parsing result */
%}

%%
FIREFOX {global_variable = TFIREFOX; yyterminate();}
MSIE {global_variable = TMSIE; yyterminate();}
. {}
%%

int lex_strstr(char *buf, int n)
{
    global_variable = -1;
    YY_BUFFER_STATE bs = yy_scan_buffer(buf, n);
    yy_switch_to_buffer(bs);
    yylex();
    return global_variable;
}
```

Store it in some file like `resulte.l` and use flex to compile it to get a c header file:

```
flex -o head.h result.l
```

And here's an example to show how this work:

```
#include "head.h"
int main()
{
    {
        char buf[] = "this is a test MSIE string\0\0";
        printf("%d\n", lex_strstr(buf, (sizeof buf)));
    }
    {
        char buf[] = "this is a test FIREFOX string\0\0";
        printf("%d\n", lex_strstr(buf, (sizeof buf)));
    }
    {
        char buf[] = "this is a test MSIEFIREFOX string\0\0";
        printf("%d\n", lex_strstr(buf, (sizeof buf)));
    }
    {
        char buf[] = "this is a test MIEFIEFOXdfa\0\0";
        printf("%d\n", lex_strstr(buf, (sizeof buf)));
    }
}
```

with result:

```
1
0
1
-1
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, will definetely check this out!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your strings to length prefixed.

Lots of time is wasted looking for the terminating nul character in C strings and a length prefixed string does away with that waste while adding little overhead of its own.

There is a library in the wild that is either BSD or MIT licensed (read: Free to use for anyone) which is pretty optimized and has a very low bug count.  However, for the life of me I can't think of the name of the lib.  It *might* be Safestr. Look [here](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/271-BSI.html) for hints to find Safestr or [here](http://www.zork.org/safestr/) if the page will load for you.